# @Resource not injecting SessionContext in jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, resteasy

I am exposing a singleton EJB as restful service; requirement is to initiate a timer via Rest API. As this is going to be web app, i am packing ejb class in war file. I am successfully able to deploy the bean and invoke the web service, but could not initiate the timer as @Resource annotation is not injecting SessionContext in the aforementioned singleton ejb (tried with stateless session bean as well). When debugged I see SessionContext object is null. Any suggestions on how I can make the timer service work in this scenario? Below are details:

- JBoss 7.1.1 Final
- RestEasy 2.3.7 Final
- Java 7

---

TimerSessionBean.java:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Singleton
@Path("/config")
public class TimerSessionBean {

   @Resource
   private SessionContext context;

   @GET
   @Path("{id}")
   public void createTimer(@PathParam("id") long duration) {
       context.getTimerService().createTimer(duration, "Hello World!");
   }

   @Timeout
   public void timeOutHandler(Timer timer) {
       System.out.println("timeoutHandler : " + timer.getInfo());       
   }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
      <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

AppConfig.java:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AppConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
         Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
         set.add(TimerSessionBean.class);
         return set;
    }
}
```

Excerpt from server log:

```
20:09:08,850 INFO [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named TimerSessionBean in deployment unit deployment "myapp-1.0.war" are as follows:
    java:global/myapp-1.0/TimerSessionBean!app.ws.resources.TimerSessionBean
java:app/myapp-1.0/TimerSessionBean!app.ws.resources.TimerSessionBean
java:module/TimerSessionBean!app.ws.resources.TimerSessionBean
java:global/myapp-1.0/TimerSessionBean
java:app/myapp-1.0/TimerSessionBean
java:module/TimerSessionBean
```

Answer (score 1):

You are packaging your ejb inside a war file, which implies that your are using [EJB 3.1 Lite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/javaee6overview-part3-139660.html#ejblite) that is a [reduced set](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/FeatureMatrixEJB3InAS6) of ejb features.
I'm not sure why the SessionContext instance is not injected, 
but take in mind that the TimerService is not available in this reduced version of ejb specification.